# Gmail API Users.settings.sendAs: update, does not reflect on web client unless reloaded

Tags: gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API [Users.settings.sendAs: update](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/update) to automatically update the signature settings of our users. The issue I'm having is the change in the signature does not get reflected in the Gmail web client unless the web page gets reloaded. Our users can spend several days, even couple of weeks, without reloading their Gmail web page, making the update almost useless.

I would like to know if there is a way for the web client to pick up the new settings once the changes are made through the API without requiring the user to reload the page?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch) feature in Gmail API. This lets you watch for changes to Gmail mailboxes. You can use this feature to improve the performance of your application. Whenever a mailbox changes, the Gmail API notifies your backend server application.

Then, you may proceed with [Synchronizing Clients with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync) if you need to process changes. As discussed in the documentation, you can also use push notifications to trigger partial synchronization in real-time and only when necessary.

Hope that helps!